# How to parse an url in php with authentification

Tags: php, parsing, curl, cookies

I'm trying to parse a webpage with php and curl behind a login but I don't get what is wrong. I have read dozen of topics without success.

My first step is to post on the login page to get a cookie and to save it inside a file.
My second step is to use this cookie to access the second page and parse it.

Here is my code, thanks for your help!

```
<?php
$cookiefile = "/var/www/html/a-cki.txt";
$loginUrl = 'myurl/login.php';
$parseUrl = 'myurl/index.php';

$postinfo = "username=xxx&password=xxx&login=xxx";

//Login and save cookie
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Download another page while reusing the cookie
$parse = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_URL, $parseUrl);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$parseResponse = curl_exec( $parse );
curl_close($parse);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe this one: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);`? Maybe you have to follow some redirect to get the cookie? And try to remove `curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);`

Comment: Just to be clear, remove `curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);` from the second curl instance

Comment: Thanks, I did both and it solved it!!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Armin Šupuk comment!

```
$postinfo = "username=xxx&password=xxx&login=xxx";

//Login and save cookie
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Download another page while reusing the cookie
$parse = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_URL, $parseUrl);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$parseResponse = curl_exec( $parse );
curl_close($parse);

?>
```